Асинхронный ли aiogram на самом деле?
Только что прочитал статью на хабре про асинхронное программирование (сама статья)
И мне стало довольно непонятно как работает aiogram, потому что, как я понял, нужно каждое асинхронное действие оборачивать в задачу и отправлять в asycnio.create_task(), а затем это вызывать через await. НО, буквально каждый тутор по aiogram дает такой синтаксис, что я реально засомневался в том, что там асинхронно выполняются действия.
Я сам относительно начинающий и уверен, что дело в том, что я чего-то не понимаю или что-то упустил. Раскройте мне мои глаза :)

Не очень понятно в чём проблема у вас, вся идея асинхронности как раз в том, что event loop крутит в своём цикле вот эти самые таски, периодически передавая им управление, когда случаются ожидаемые этими тасками события (получение данных в сокете и т. п.), и aiogram тут ничем не отличается

нет не нужно. асинк функции сами по себе корутины и их достаточно вызывать в правильном контексте. Оборачивать в asycnio.create_task() нужно только если вам нужен объект Task с его возможностями (иначе сами по себе async функции возвращают объект корутины, который пригоден разве что для await).

@vitidev create_task конечно необязателен, но штука в том, что если таски не создавать, то в программе будет один-единственный таск, из-за чего в асинхронности по сути не будет смысла. Впрочем, возможно, таски создаются где-то неявно, например внутри того же aiogram

"нужно каждое асинхронное действие оборачивать в задачу и отправлять в asycnio.create_task(), а затем это вызывать через await" - не нужно. Если нужно сразу дождаться завершения - просто добавляйте await. Если нужно, чтобы корутина продолжала работать в фоне - тогда нужен asyncio.create_task, и await добавлять в этом случае не нужно.
